# Keras Elephas ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_43 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (3,)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, elephas

Would appreciate some help as I have so far tried everything on other threads with no luck. I am getting this dimension issue with my keras pyspark pipeline while doing the following, it's a multi-class classification with three classes, I did not one-hot encode the target label and am using sparse-categorical crossentropy:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
pipeline_model=pipeline.fit(df)
df_transform=pipeline_model.transform(df)

df_transform = df_transform.select("features","label_index" )
train_data, test_data = df_transform_fin.randomSplit([0.80,0.2], seed=42)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(input_dim,),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(input_dim,),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


optimizer_conf = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.3)
opt_conf=optimizers.serialize(optimizer_conf)

estimator=ElephasEstimator()
estimator.setFeaturesCol("features")
estimator.setLabelCol("label_index")
estimator.set_keras_model_config(model.to_yaml())
estimator.set_categorical_labels(True)
estimator.set_nb_classes(classes)
estimator.set_num_workers(8)
estimator.set_epochs(2909)
estimator.set_batch_size(4096)
estimator.set_verbosity(1)
estimator.set_validation_split(0.20)
estimator.set_optimizer_config(opt_conf)
estimator.set_mode('synchronous')
estimator.set_loss('sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
estimator.set_metrics(['acc'])

dl_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[estimator])

def dl_pipeline_fit_score_results(dl_pipeline=dl_pipeline, train_data=train_data, test_data=test_data, label='label_index'):
  fit_dl_pipeline=dl_pipeline.fit(train_data)
  pred_train = fit_dl_pipeline.transform(train_data)
  pred_test = fit_dl_pipeline.transform(test_data)

dl_pipeline_fit_score_results(dl_pipeline=dl_pipeline, train_data=train_data, test_data=test_data, label='label_index')
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              585728    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 12291     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 3)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 17,379,331
Trainable params: 17,379,331
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Even with the last layer being 
`model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))` the same error happens.

Sample train data:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|            features|label_index|
+--------------------+-----------+
|(142,[0,1,2,3,4,5...|        1.0|
|(142,[0,1,2,3,4,5...|        0.0|
|(142,[0,1,2,3,4,5...|        0.0|
|(142,[0,1,2,3,4,5...|        2.0|
|(142,[0,1,2,3,4,5...|        0.0|
```

Would appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: in your layer summary there is only dense 44 ? where is dense_43 ? also what is the shape of your input and output ? 
Do you use any pretrained model and then add this at the end ?

Comment: sorry about that, I have the right model summary put in the post above now, I had a weird model summary up here, apologies. As per the shape, I have little experience with pyspark ml and believe I have sparse vectors that come from my pipeline under 'features' and the length of each vector is 142... I pasted a sample of my train data for your reference, I've got 8M records in train data @venkatakrishnan

Comment: in your model code, why there is an input_shape again for the second dense layer ? after the first dropout ?